# How to prevent react-persist store the data to local storage for some cases?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

Hi we are developing web application using React JS and using the react-persist for state management. React-persist store the state data's to localstorage. But i need to skip this storing logic from some cases like user login data. How to do this.

Sample Reducer :

```
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {GET_DATA, GET_DATA_SUCCESS} from "./configAction"

const initialState = {};
  
  export const reducer = persistReducer(
  { storage, key: "config"},
    (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
          switch (type) {
              case GET_DATA:
                  return{
                      ...state,
                      isLoading: true,
                  };
                  case GET_DATA_SUCCESS:
                      return payload.data.data.config
              default:
                  return state
          }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

In `redux-persist` there is something called as `blackList` which you can use to exclude the data from getting persisted .

Suppose you have a data in your store as

```
{ 
  appData: { key1: {} , key2: {} }
}
```

Now if you do not want to persist the `Key1` and its values, you can do something like

```
const appDataPersistConfig = {
  key: 'appData',
  storage: storage // import this from redux-persist
  blackList: [ 'key1' ]
}
```

[BlackList and WhiteList](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist) - Please refer this.